# Custom Cursor java

Tags: java, cursor

So my issue is that on Saturday I made a custom frame in Java and I made it so the user        can move the frame. I got that working. Now my question is that I have a label which gives my users the ability to move the frame around and I was wondering how would I make it so when the users is clicking or the mouse is in the  label, it shows a Cursor that I have made. I was just wondering what code would I use for this.

Comment: may be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274606/how-to-change-cursor-icon-in-java?rq=1 ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your MouseListener you can use:

```
event.getComponent().setCursor(...);
```

Read the Cursor API for more information. You can use the getPredefinedCursor() method.

The mousePressed() method would set the cursor. Then in the mouseReleased() method you would set the cursor to null to restore the default cursor.

Edit:

To use a custom cursor the basic code would be:

```
Cursor custom = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createCustomCursor(...);
```

and you provide the image to use for the Cursor.

Comment: i know how to use default cursors i wanted to use the one i made