# Cursor blinking while taking capture screen

Tags: java, screenshot

I use this code to make 100 screen captures:

```
Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
            BufferedImage capture = new Robot().createScreenCapture(screenRect);
            ImageIO.write(capture, "jpg", new File("D:/pictures/pic" + i + ".jpg"));
        }
```

Why is the cursor blinking when are taking the captures? Is something wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is nothing wrong with your code. From the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#createScreenCapture%28java.awt.Rectangle%29):

> This image does not include the mouse cursor.

So Java hides the cursor momentarily in order to take the screenshot, then it makes it visible again.

Comment: Thank you for responding me. Is there any way to not blink the cursor?

Comment: With standard Java, I don't think so, I can't see anything relevant in the Javadocs. If you really want to do it, you should do something with JNI and the Windows C API, this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/531684/what-is-the-best-way-to-take-screenshots-of-a-window-with-c-in-windows

Comment: Make an invisible cursor, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274606/how-to-change-cursor-icon-in-java (afterwards restore it)

Comment: I wonder why Camtasia does blink similarly. It does take the cursor into capture.