# Java registering events through window

Tags: java, window, transparency

What I would like in Java is to create a transparent screen over the entire screen that does not respond to events such as mouse or keyboard. Essentially, the user won't even know about the screen. How would I make the window "transparent" to events?

Comment: you mean you want the entire application to be full screen and invisible?

Comment: Yes. Essentially, I want a window that exists but does not do anything. It also allows events to go through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Creating a Translucent Window](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html).

You would use an opacity of 0.0f.

Edit:

With an opacity of 0.0f the events go through the frame to the component below, therefore the window you click on will come to the front.

With a non-zero opacity (ie 0.05f) the events are intercepted by the frame.

You may also need to use:

```
frame.setAlwaysOnTop( true );
```

to prevent the window from coming to the front.

Play with the opacity and always on top property to get your desired effect. If these two properties don't work then I have no ideas to do what you are asking, nor do I understand the requirement.

Comment: Yes, but when I click, the event causes the window behind to come front, and I want the transparent frame to stay in front.

Comment: @JamesSmith, in your original question you stated: `It also allows events to go through it.` -  which is why I suggested an opacity of 0.0f. See edit.